# How to transfer files from one server to another?

Tags: server, file-sharing

I have two servers online both have dedicated ips both are 12.04 and with plesk panel. the problem is on my one server the files are more than 11 gb i wan to transfer them from one server to another what is the best possible solution for this ? both servers has good internet speeds and online 24 hours i want to transfer them from one to another.

FTP ? SSH ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using one server to backup another you could use rsync. It does a full transfer the first time then any transfer after that it only does the changed files/new files.

I use it to for my backup servers.

Comment: it can transfer 11 gb ?

Comment: and i am worried how much time it can take ?

Comment: I used it to transfer 48 gb at first. I did it over the weekend so I'm not exactly sure how long it took.

Answer (score 7):

You can use SCP (Secure Copy

```
scp <file> <username>@<IP address or hostname>:<Destination>
```

Example:

```
scp "TPS Reports.odw" joe@laptop:Desktop/
```

Link for more information [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/TransferFiles)

Comment: it can transfer 11 GB

Comment: Yes you can.If they are on the same network there will be no problem

Comment: no they are over internet not in same network one server is in germany and other is in spain ?

Comment: Yes you can use it. Just be sure to have a stable internet connection.